# Does ServiceStack / Funq support injections of generic members?

Tags: servicestack, funq

My service base class has generic public property

```
public IProvider<TRequest, TResponse> Provider;
```

which I am trying to inject with

```
container.Register<IProvider<GetAccount, GetAccountResponse>>(c => new AccountProvider());
```

but that does not work (property is null) while other non-generic properties are initialized.

Should it (can I make it) work?

Answer (score 2):

This is a public field:

```
public IProvider<TRequest, TResponse> Provider;
```

Add a getter/setter to make it a public property:

```
public IProvider<TRequest, TResponse> Provider { get; set; }
```

Which Funq does support.